# Why is my input button not aligned in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s04eg.png)

I try to create a virtual keyboard in my web, but my input button have word and haven't word can't align.

Why does this happen? Where is my problem?

```
<input id="kb_~" type="button" value="1" class="keyboard" />
<input id="kb_ㄅ" type="button" value="" class="keyboard" />
<input id="kb_ㄉ" type="button" value="ㄉ" class="keyboard" />
<input id="kb_3sound" type="button" value="ˇ" class="keyboard"  />
<input id="kb_4sound" type="button" value="ˋ" class="keyboard" />
```

I want to align my button before with word and without word

Comment: First, it's unclear what you want to happen. Second, without the rest of the HTML source and the stylesheet it's impossible to say. The only thing that affects layout in this snippet is the `keyboard` CSS class, which is missing. The layout may be affected by other classes too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET though. It's all HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with asp.net.The problem is with CSS & Html. Please use HTML table able CSS to correctly design key bord.
Please download and try the below code.
[This is an old and simple example. Please try this.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ab9j48b889vfp1s/Virtual_Keyboard.zip/file)

Comment: Please add code here itself to support your argument. Kindly do not host your code elsewhere